# currentTarget is not working on android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a knockout binding on Tap

```
<a class="scroll icon-arrow-down" data-anchor="#part" data-bind="localizedText: { id: '4-anchor-1', html: true }, tap: controller.scrollTo.bind(controller)"></a>
```

This should get the target attr data-anchor this works on desktop but not on android..

```
scrollTo()
{
    alert($(event.currentTarget).attr("data-anchor"));
}
```

Gives undefined on android.

Comment: try to add parameter `event` to your `scrollTo` function. So it would be `scrollTo(event)`

Comment: @MysterX Tried that. Now both platforms give a undefined on desktop and android :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to the function called from an `event` binding is the current item (`$data`), and the second is the event object. Assuming the (nonstandard) `tap` binding is defined similarly, your function should be defined:

```
scrollTo(data, event)
{
    alert($(event.currentTarget).attr("data-anchor"));
}
```